# Parametric equation of tangent question involving a circle

Tags: circles

Given a circle centered at the origin with radius $5$, find the parametric equation of the tangent line to the circle at the point $(3, −4)$.

The final equation is supposed to be like this: $$(3,-4) + t(x,y).$$

The problem is that I don't know what are the values of $x$ and $y$. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

The radius is perpedicular to the tangent line.

Can you find a solution to $$3x-4y=0?$$

Comment: since its perpendicular, i need to use dot product = 0 . and then find the the value of x and y? am i right?

Comment: yup, I am taking the dot product, you just need a solution fo $x$ and $y$ to determine the direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Draw a radius from the origin to $(3, -4)$. This line must be perpendicular to the desired tangent line. So the two lines' corresponding direction vectors must have a dot product of zero.

Alternatively, recall that the slopes of perpendicular lines must have a product of $-1$.

Comment: do you mean dot product of the origin and perpendicular line = 0? because im still not quiet understand.

Comment: If $ac+bd=0$, then $ac= -bd$, if $b \neq 0$, then we have $\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{d}{c}$ or equivalently, $\frac{a}{b}\frac{c}{d}=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

***x*** and ***y*** are co-ordinate points of the tangent line and their values depend on the given value for parameter (***t***).
The parametric equation of the tangent line can be written as,

x = 3(1+t), y = -4(1-t)

The point (3,-4) represents co-ordinate point on the tangent line for t=0
Similarly, other co-ordinate points on the tangent line will be obtained for giving values for t = ....-3, -2 -1 etc., and 1, 2, 3,....etc

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).